# My remove() method on my own ArrayBasedList Class removing wrong index

Tags: java, arraylist

I've finally figured out my insert correctly but for days I've been working on the remove method and it just will not give me the output I want. My remove method is removing only the last index and not at the position I specified. My method must be a boolean with an int position parameter brought it to the method. What must I do to get my code to remove an object at the specified position parameter given, not the last index. 
My code is below...

```
public class ArrayBasedList<T> implements ListInterface<T>{
    private int MAX_ITEMS = 20;      // Maximum Number of items the items array can hold.
    private Item<T>[] items;        // Array that will hold items of type T
    private int count;          // Number of valid items in the array  

    ArrayBasedList(){
        items = new Item[MAX_ITEMS];
        count = 0;
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        if(isFull()) return;
        items[count] =  new Item(item);
        count++;
    }

    public void insert(int position, T item) {
        for(int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(position > count || position > MAX_ITEMS) return;
            if(items[position] == items[count]){
                count++;
                add(item);
                items[i].data = items[i+1].data;
            }
            items[position].data = item;
        }
    }

    public T get(int position) {
        if(position < 0 || position >= count) { 
            throw new RuntimeException("Index out of Bounds. ");
        }
        return items[position].data;
    }


    public boolean set(int position, T item) {
        if(position > count || position > MAX_ITEMS) return false;
        items[position].data = item;
        return true;
    }

//METHOD THAT IS GIVING ME AN ISSUE
    public boolean remove(int position) {
        if(isEmpty() || position > count || position > MAX_ITEMS) return false;
        for(int i = count-1; i < position; i--) {
            if(items[i] == items[position]) {
                items[i].data = items[i-1].data;
            }
            items[i] = items[position];
        }
        count--;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        if(count >= MAX_ITEMS) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(count == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Prints my List
    public void printAll() {
        for(int i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(items[i].toString());
        }
    }

    //Counts number of objects in list
    public int size() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Output that is expected is specified in the print statement above my reprinted list... the output i get is removed at the last index, not at specified position.

```
OUTPUT:
The list is as follows: 
[1.0x2.0x3.0]
[2.0x3.0x4.0]
[3.0x4.0x5.0]
[4.0x5.0x6.0]
[5.0x6.0x7.0]
[6.0x7.0x8.0]
[7.0x8.0x9.0]
[8.0x9.0x10.0]
[9.0x10.0x11.0]
[10.0x11.0x12.0]

Size of my list is 11

Attempting to remove item at location 0.
The current list is as follows: 
[1.0x2.0x3.0]
[2.0x3.0x4.0]
[3.0x4.0x5.0]
[4.0x5.0x6.0]
[5.0x6.0x7.0]
[6.0x7.0x8.0]
[7.0x8.0x9.0]
[8.0x9.0x10.0]
[9.0x10.0x11.0]

Size of my list is 10

Attempting to remove item at location 5.
The current list is as follows: 
[1.0x2.0x3.0]
[2.0x3.0x4.0]
[3.0x4.0x5.0]
[4.0x5.0x6.0]
[5.0x6.0x7.0]
[6.0x7.0x8.0]
[7.0x8.0x9.0]
[8.0x9.0x10.0]

Size of my list is 9

Attempting to insert a cube 100*200*300 at location 9.
The current list is as follows: 
[1.0x2.0x3.0]
[2.0x3.0x4.0]
[3.0x4.0x5.0]
[4.0x5.0x6.0]
[5.0x6.0x7.0]
[6.0x7.0x8.0]
[7.0x8.0x9.0]
[8.0x9.0x10.0]
[10.0x11.0x12.0]
[100.0x200.0x300.0]

Size of my list is 11

Attempting to insert a cube 100*200*300 at location 3.
The current list is as follows: 
[1.0x2.0x3.0]
[2.0x3.0x4.0]
[3.0x4.0x5.0]
[100.0x200.0x300.0]
[5.0x6.0x7.0]
[6.0x7.0x8.0]
[7.0x8.0x9.0]
[8.0x9.0x10.0]
[10.0x11.0x12.0]
[100.0x200.0x300.0]

Size of my list is 11

Attempting to set the value at location 5 to a cube 10*11.2*20.9.
The current list is as follows: 
[1.0x2.0x3.0]
[2.0x3.0x4.0]
[3.0x4.0x5.0]
[100.0x200.0x300.0]
[5.0x6.0x7.0]
[10.0x11.2x20.9]
[7.0x8.0x9.0]
[8.0x9.0x10.0]
[10.0x11.0x12.0]
[100.0x200.0x300.0]

The current size of the list is: 11
The value at position 3 is: [100.0x200.0x300.0]
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger yet?  Always do that before asking for help, 98% of the time you will find the problem yourself and learn something in the process.  Much more rewarding.

Comment: @JimGarrison I did try to debug it. Usually this does solve my issue and I completely agree It helps me learn the process, but after debugging twice and tracing once I don't know why I am not able to find the issue this time and my assignment was due yesterday so I just don't want to loose any further points. But thank you for your input I always appreciate any constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method.

```
public boolean remove(int position) {
    if(isEmpty() && position>count && position > MAX_ITEMS){
        return false
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (items[i] == position) {
                --count;
                for (; i < count; ++i) {
                    items[i].data = items[i + 1].data;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;        
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed one line... from { if (items[i] == position) } to { if(items[i] == items[position] ) }.